# Deletion of paragraphs containing specified text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created Word VBA code to remove paragraphs from multiple pages.

Having issues deleting paragraphs containing (APL) with `Or InStr(doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, "(APL)") > 0 Then`

Example text:
FRUIT//APL BAN//

```vb
Sub DeleteSpecificParagraphs()
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Dim i As Long

    For i = doc.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, "(APPLE)") > 0 _
          Or InStr(doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, "(APPLE/ORANGES)") > 0 _
          Or InStr(doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, "(ORANGES)") > 0 _
          Or InStr(doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, "(AP)") > 0 _
          Or InStr(doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, "(APL)") > 0 Then
            doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Cannot bold text within code

Comment: HI, I only did that here to highlight the problem line.

Comment: this line does not work properly: Or InStr(doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, "(APL)") > 0 Then

Comment: What does it mean `not properly`. Care of lower and uppercase.

Comment: Can you attach the text involved?

Comment: More practical to add a comment to the queer line with the short description of the problem e.g. `' <- this is the line which errors`  ,when sy test immediatly see if the error is caused in that line or somewhere else.

Comment: there is no error per se. The line simply does not do what it was created to do. I am not sure how much clearer I can get. Everything else works fine except that line reflected above.

Comment: @Blackcat Thank you for that but I tried Uppercase and lower and both do not work.

Comment: it does not remove the paragraph that contains the APL text, but rest of the VBA works just fine. I do not believe it's a case of UPPER/lower case.

Comment: Are you sure the sting _(APL)_ appears? (try to search for the text manually)

Comment: Hi, yes it does. I have slashes such as FRUIT//APL BAN//, is that what's messing it up?

Comment: Please post a short example text. btw _(APL)_ appears not in _//APL BAN_

Comment: The code above can be simplified because lines 1,2,4 and 5 of the if statement can all be  addressed by the single "Instr(doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text) or "(AP" if you need the opening bracket.  The situation would be different if the if statement were a select case.

Comment: It would also be sensible to read the text of doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text once into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Trim to remove white spacee, and the UCase  to make the comparison case-insensitive.  See edited code below.

```
    Sub DeleteSpecificParagraphs()
        Dim doc As Document
        Set doc = ActiveDocument
        Dim i As Long
    
        For i = doc.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
            Dim paraText As String
            paraText = Trim(doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text) ' Trim removes white spaces
            
            ' UCase for case-insensitive
            If InStr(1, UCase(paraText), "(APPLE)") > 0 _
            Or InStr(1, UCase(paraText), "(APPLE/ORANGES)") > 0 _
            Or InStr(1, UCase(paraText), "(ORANGES)") > 0 _
            Or InStr(1, UCase(paraText), "(AP)") > 0 _
            Or InStr(1, UCase(paraText), "(APL)") > 0 Then
            doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: hi @vbakim, the code did not work

Comment: That's strange, I always tested my code before posting.  I pasted above code into word 365 and it removed all the lines have (...) lines. Isn't it what you want?
Can you post some of doc sample for test?

Comment: @vbakim example in comment to the question FRUIT//APL BAN//. This does not contain (APL).